# Problem with multiple raster plot

Tags: raster, ggplot2, multi

This is my code to try plotting three different rasters with ggplot2. However, when I run the code just one raster is displayed.

What could the problem be?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggthemes)
library(RStoolbox)

stack_df <- stack(list(soer, jacr, brayr)) %>% fortify()

rsdf <- as.data.frame(stack_df)
head(rsdf)
beta_plot <- ggplot(rsdf, aes(x, y, fill=layer.1)) +
  geom_raster( aes(x = x, y = y, fill = layer.1)) +
  ggtitle('Beta-diversity Index') +
  scale_fill_viridis_c() +
  coord_sf()

beta_plot
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. It is unclear what the extents of the rasters might be (if the all share one extent, then the output here could not demonstrate the issue). Please [Edit] the Question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to bring your data into long-form to work with ggplot2.
Currently you have it in wide-form, i.e. each layer in a separate column.
For example:

```r
       x       y layer.1 layer.2 layer.3
1 620830 -411755      64      25      21
2 623700 -411755      58      22      14
```

should be

```r
       x       y variable value
1 620830 -411755  layer.1    64
2 623700 -411755  layer.1    58
3 620830 -411755  layer.2    25
4 623700 -411755  layer.2    22
5 620830 -411755  layer.3    21
6 623700 -411755  layer.3    14
```

This will do the transformation:

```r
library(tidyr)
raster <- stack(list(soer, jacr, brayr))
stack_df <- raster %>%
   fortify() %>% 
   gather(variable,value,-x,-y)
```

Now you need to change the ggplot accordingly.

```r
ggplot(stack_df, aes(x, y, fill=value)) +
   geom_raster() +
   scale_fill_viridis_c() +
   facet_wrap(~variable)
```

#### Two more comments:

a) there is the RStoolbox built-in `ggR()` function, which does the same thing under the hood, if you specify multiple bands, but which works directly from the raster(stack):

```r
ggR(raster, layer = 1:3, geom_raster = TRUE) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c()
```

b) be aware that, by default, both `fortify()` and `ggR()` use only a subset of all pixels to construct the plot (since rasters are often large). However you can increase that sample up to the total number of pixels with the  `maxpixels` argument, e.g. `maxpixels=ncell(raster)` would use all pixels.